# Fancy indexing in assignment not supported for csr matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I efficiently assign to a row in a `csr_matrix`?

This gives the error:

```
Q[mid, :] = new_Q
```

`Q` is a `csr_matrix`, and `new_Q` is the result of `Q.getrow(i)`.

I'm using the latest version of scipy.

Am I using the right matrix type?

I want to find the right matrix type for two matrices I'm using: `Q` and `B`.
I'm modifying one **row** of matrix Q at a time, and modifying one **column** of B at a time. It seems like I should create `Q` as a `lil_matrix` or a `csr_matrix`. What type of matrix should `B` be? A `csc_matrix`?

Comment: What are `B` and `A`?  I only see `Q` and `new_Q`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in 13.2:

```
>>> sp.__version__
'0.13.2'
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> a = sps.csr_matrix(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5))
>>> a.A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a[3] = a.getrow(0)
>>> a.A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

As for the answer to your second question, it depends on whether you are changing the sparsity pattern of the rows (columns) or not. If you are not, then yes, CSR for row, CSC for columns. But if you are, then CSR and CSC are going to struggle, because every row (column) update is going to require copying the data for the whole matrix every time. In this latter case you may want to try to use LIL for both your `Q` and `B` matrices, but work with `B.T` so that you are accessing rows.

Comment: I found the problem is I'm running scipy version 0.11.0. `sudo pip install scipy --update` hadn't updated it. When I run `sudo pip uninstall scipy` I find that `import scipy; scipy.__version__` still prints `0.11.0`. How can I find and remove the old package? I see that the uninstall command successfully removed the scipy directory from `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.